# ajuda com a solução desta EDO

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Alguém poderia me ajudar no desenvolvimento da Questão: $y''-a(x^n)y=0$ ?

Ps:. A solução desta questão eu conheço, mas o desenvolvimento eu não consigo manipular de modo a chegar na solução.

English Translation:

Can anyone help me to understand how to find the solution of the problem:$y''-a(x^n)y=0$?

Ps: I know the solution, however, I do not know how to find it.

Comment: Can you give an approximate translation to English?  You can just add this as an edit (without removing your original question).  If you get it fairly close, I'll help fix the grammar and spelling...

Comment: Além disso, estou interessado em ver a solução para este problema. Você pode por favor compartilhá-lo?

Comment: A solução final é bastante longa, eu gastaria muito tempo digitando...gostaria que eu lhe enviasse por email? se quiser me envie seu email...

Answer (score 1):

(Relying on Google to do the translation)

Maple escreve a solução geral como esta:
$$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,\sqrt {x}{{ J}_{ \left( n+2
 \right) ^{-1}}\left(2\,{\frac {\sqrt {-a}{x}^{n/2+1}}{n+2}}\right)}+{
\it \_C2}\,\sqrt {x}{{ Y}_{ \left( n+2 \right) ^{-1}}\left(2\,{
\frac {\sqrt {-a}{x}^{n/2+1}}{n+2}}\right)}
$$
onde $ J $ e $ Y $ são funções de Bessel.

Você pode obtê-lo, olhando para a relação de recorrência para soluções como a série em potências de $x$, e reconhecendo a série para estas funções de Bessel.

Maple writes the general solution as this:

$$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,\sqrt {x}{{ J}_{ \left( n+2
 \right) ^{-1}}\left(2\,{\frac {\sqrt {-a}{x}^{n/2+1}}{n+2}}\right)}+{
\it \_C2}\,\sqrt {x}{{ Y}_{ \left( n+2 \right) ^{-1}}\left(2\,{
\frac {\sqrt {-a}{x}^{n/2+1}}{n+2}}\right)}
$$
where $J$ and $Y$ are Bessel functions.

You could get it by looking at the recurrence relation for solutions as series in powers of $x$, and recognizing the series for these Bessel functions.

Comment: Exatamente, a solução é esta mesma...mas no meu caso, o problema não é a solução final, mas sim o desenvolvimento para chegar até esta, entendeu?

Comment: Seeking the development of EDO posted as I have the final solution, but the development is not known!